# how to refresh my page when returning a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reload

I am redirecting to a page after there are changes on the page. However, I can only see the changes after I actually reload the entire page.

I'm redirecting to this page like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    return View(Function(id));
}
```

Is there something I may be able to put in my parameter that could refresh the page?

Comment: Where is the redirect?

Comment: This is going to build the `Details` view and send it the string `id` for its model. Is that what you want or are you wanting to display an entirely different view like `Summary` for example?

Comment: I'm displaying a view and passing an object which I'm using as a model in my Details UI

Comment: OK, so I think there is some pretty important code missing here, how are you building the model (i.e. `object`) you're sending to the `View` method?

Comment: I'm building the model in a different function. I didn't show it here since I don't believe it to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

OK this is a common mistake that people make when dealing with ASP.NET MVC. You don't want to return the **View** instead you just want to redirect properly.

```
public ActionResult Detail(string id) {
    // actual redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Function", new { id });
}
```

This will make sure your controller makes an actual redirect, and not just displaying the view. This also insures your routes / url are valid. Hope this helps :)